# How to store multiple fields data into same variable using php?

Tags: php, mysql, implode

I am new to PHP. I have a form in which I used `input type text` now I want to store multiple field data into same column of mysql db.

[image]

For example, according to above picture i want to store all opinions in one column, all rating types in one column and so on.

I googled for this problem, and I found implode as the solution. But I don't know how I can use it.

```
<table width="800" height="194" border="1" >
  <tr> <td>Id</td> 
  <td colspan="8"><input type="text" name="company_id" value="<?php echo $row['pr_client']?>" size="5" readonly/> </td></tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="234" rowspan="3"><b>Opinion</b></td>
            <td width="129" rowspan="3"><b>Rating Type</b></td>
            <td width="74" rowspan="3"><b>Action</b></td>
            <td width="89" rowspan="3"><b>Outlook</b></td>
            <td height="58" colspan="4"><div align="center"><b>              Ratings            </b></div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2"><div align="center"><b>           Long Term   </b>      </div></td>
          <td colspan="2"><div align="center">  <b>     Short Term  </b>      </div></td>
  </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="55"><b>Current</b></td>
          <td width="62"><b>Previous</b></td>
          <td width="55"><b>Current</b></td>
          <td width="66"><b>Previous</b></td>
      </tr>
        <tr>
         <td width="234" rowspan="2"><input type="text" name="first_opinion_name" value="<?php echo $row['opinion']?>" size="32"/></td>
         <td width="129" rowspan="2"><input type="text" name="first_opinion_rating_type" value="<?php echo $row['ttitle'] ?>" 
          size="10"/></td>
        <td width="74" rowspan="2"><input type="text" name="first_opinion_action" value="<?php echo $row['atitle'] ?>" size="06"/></td>
        <td width="89" rowspan="2"><input type="text" name="first_opinion_outlook" value="<?php echo $row['otitle'] ?>" size="05"/></td>
           <tr>
          <td width="55"><input type="text" name="first_opinion_long_term" value="<?php echo $row['ltitle'] ?>" size="05"/></td>
          <td width="62"><input type="text" name="first_opinion_p_long_term" value="<?php echo $row1['ltitle'] ?>" size="05"/></td>
          <td width="55"><input type="text" name="first_opinion_short_term" value="<?php echo $row['stitle'] ?>" size="05"/></td>
          <td width="62"><input type="text" name="first_opinion_p_short_term" value="<?php echo $row1['stitle'] ?>" size="05"/></td>
      </tr>


        <tr>
        <td width="234" rowspan="2"><input type="text" name="second_opinion_name" value="<?php echo $row2['opinion']?>" size="32"/></td>
        <td width="129" rowspan="2"><input type="text" name="second_opinion_rating_type" value="<?php echo $row2['ttitle'] ?>" 
          size="10"/></td>
       <td width="74" rowspan="2"><input type="text" name="second_opinion_action" value="<?php echo $row2['atitle'] ?>" size="06"/></td>
      <td width="89" rowspan="2"><input type="text" name="second_opinion_outlook" value="<?php echo $row2['otitle'] ?>" size="05"/></td>
           <tr>
          <td width="55"><input type="text" name="second_opinion_long_term" value="<?php echo $row2['ltitle'] ?>" size="05"/></td>
          <td width="62"><input type="text" name="second_opinion_p_long_term" value="<?php echo $row3['ltitle'] ?>" size="05"/></td>
          <td width="55"><input type="text" name="second_opinion_short_term" value="<?php echo $row2['stitle'] ?>" size="05"/></td>
          <td width="62"><input type="text" name="second_opinion_p_short_term" value="<?php echo $row3['stitle'] ?>" size="05"/></td>
      </tr>
                      </tr>


          <tr>
    <td width="234" rowspan="2"><input type="text" name="third_opinion_name" value="<?php echo $row4['opinion']?>" size="32"/></td>
  <td width="129" rowspan="2"><input type="text" name="third_opinion_rating_type" value="<?php echo $row4['ttitle'] ?>"size="10"/></td>
  <td width="74" rowspan="2"><input type="text" name="third_opinion_action" value="<?php echo $row4['atitle'] ?>" size="06"/></td>
  <td width="89" rowspan="2"><input type="text" name="third_opinion_outlook" value="<?php echo $row4['otitle'] ?>" size="05"/></td>
           <tr>
          <td width="55"><input type="text" name="third_opinion_long_term" value="<?php echo $row4['ltitle'] ?>" size="05"/></td>
          <td width="62"><input type="text" name="third_opinion_p_long_term" value="<?php echo $row5['ltitle'] ?>" size="05"/></td>
          <td width="55"><input type="text" name="third_opinion_short_term" value="<?php echo $row4['stitle'] ?>" size="05"/></td>
          <td width="62"><input type="text" name="third_opinion_p_short_term" value="<?php echo $row5['stitle'] ?>" size="05"/></td>
      </tr>

          </tr>

          <tr>
  <td width="234" rowspan="2"><input type="text" name="forth_opinion_name" value="<?php echo $row6['opinion']?>" size="32"/></td>
  <td width="129" rowspan="2"><input type="text" name="forth_opinion_rating_type" value="<?php echo $row6['ttitle'] ?>"size="10"/></td>
  <td width="74" rowspan="2"><input type="text" name="forth_opinion_action" value="<?php echo $row6['atitle'] ?>" size="06"/></td>
  <td width="89" rowspan="2"><input type="text" name="forth_opinion_outlook" value="<?php echo $row6['otitle'] ?>" size="05"/></td>
           <tr>
          <td width="55"><input type="text" name="forth_opinion_long_term" value="<?php echo $row6['ltitle'] ?>" size="05"/></td>
          <td width="62"><input type="text" name="forth_opinion_p_long_term" value="<?php echo $row7['ltitle'] ?>" size="05"/></td>
          <td width="55"><input type="text" name="forth_opinion_short_term" value="<?php echo $row6['stitle'] ?>" size="05"/></td>
          <td width="62"><input type="text" name="forth_opinion_p_short_term" value="<?php echo $row7['stitle'] ?>" size="05"/></td>
      </tr>

          </tr>
</table>
```

My Php Code is

```
$first_opinion_name = $_POST['first_opinion_name'];
$first_opinion_rating_type = $_POST['first_opinion_rating_type'];
$first_opinion_action = $_POST['first_opinion_action'];
$first_opinion_outlook = $_POST['first_opinion_outlook'];
$first_opinion_long_term = $_POST['first_opinion_long_term'];
$first_opinion_p_long_term = $_POST['first_opinion_p_long_term'];
$first_opinion_short_term = $_POST['first_opinion_short_term'];
$first_opinion_p_short_term = $_POST['first_opinion_p_short_term'];

$second_opinion_name = $_POST['second_opinion_name'];
$second_opinion_rating_type = $_POST['second_opinion_rating_type'];
$second_opinion_action = $_POST['second_opinion_action'];
$second_opinion_outlook = $_POST['second_opinion_outlook'];
$second_opinion_long_term = $_POST['second_opinion_long_term'];
$second_opinion_p_long_term = $_POST['second_opinion_p_long_term'];
$second_opinion_short_term = $_POST['second_opinion_short_term'];
$second_opinion_p_short_term = $_POST['second_opinion_p_short_term'];

$third_opinion_name = $_POST['third_opinion_name'];
$third_opinion_rating_type = $_POST['third_opinion_rating_type'];
$third_opinion_action = $_POST['third_opinion_action'];
$third_opinion_outlook = $_POST['third_opinion_outlook'];
$third_opinion_long_term = $_POST['third_opinion_long_term'];
$third_opinion_p_long_term = $_POST['third_opinion_p_long_term'];
$third_opinion_short_term = $_POST['third_opinion_short_term'];
$third_opinion_p_short_term = $_POST['third_opinion_p_short_term'];

$forth_opinion_name = $_POST['forth_opinion_name'];
$forth_opinion_rating_type = $_POST['forth_opinion_rating_type'];
$forth_opinion_action = $_POST['forth_opinion_action'];
$forth_opinion_outlook = $_POST['forth_opinion_outlook'];
$forth_opinion_long_term = $_POST['forth_opinion_long_term'];
$forth_opinion_p_long_term = $_POST['forth_opinion_p_long_term'];
$forth_opinion_short_term = $_POST['forth_opinion_short_term'];
$forth_opinion_p_short_term = $_POST['forth_opinion_p_short_term'];


$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO letter(to_name, to_designation, company, address, confidential, date, rating_type_title, opinion_type, dear_sir, company_id, first_opinion_name, first_opinion_rating_type, first_opinion_action, first_opinion_outlook, first_opinion_long_term, first_opinion_p_long_term, first_opinion_short_term, first_opinion_p_short_term, second_opinion_name, second_opinion_rating_type, second_opinion_action, second_opinion_outlook, second_opinion_long_term, second_opinion_p_long_term, second_opinion_short_term, second_opinion_p_short_term, third_opinion_name, third_opinion_rating_type, third_opinion_action, third_opinion_outlook, third_opinion_long_term, third_opinion_p_long_term, third_opinion_short_term, third_opinion_p_short_term, forth_opinion_name, forth_opinion_rating_type, forth_opinion_action, forth_opinion_outlook, forth_opinion_long_term, forth_opinion_p_long_term, forth_opinion_short_term, forth_opinion_p_short_term, y_truly, s_name, uh1, uh2, uh1_designation, uh2_designation, s_designation, chk, chk1)

values 

('$to_name', '$to_designation', '$company', '$address', '$confidential', '$Date', '$rating_type_title', '$opinion_type', '$dear_sir', '$company_id', '$first_opinion_name', '$first_opinion_rating_type', '$first_opinion_action', '$first_opinion_outlook', '$first_opinion_long_term', '$first_opinion_p_long_term', '$first_opinion_short_term', '$first_opinion_p_short_term', '$second_opinion_name', '$second_opinion_rating_type', '$second_opinion_action', '$second_opinion_outlook', '$second_opinion_long_term', '$second_opinion_p_long_term', '$second_opinion_short_term', '$second_opinion_p_short_term', '$third_opinion_name', '$third_opinion_rating_type', '$third_opinion_action', '$third_opinion_outlook',  '$third_opinion_long_term', '$third_opinion_p_long_term', '$third_opinion_short_term', '$third_opinion_p_short_term', '$forth_opinion_name', '$forth_opinion_rating_type', '$forth_opinion_action', '$forth_opinion_outlook',  '$forth_opinion_long_term', '$forth_opinion_p_long_term', '$forth_opinion_short_term', '$forth_opinion_p_short_term', '$y_truly', '$s_name', '$uh1', '$uh2', '$uh1_designation', '$uh2_designation', '$s_designation', '$chk', '$chk1')");

echo "<br/><br/><span>Data Inserted successfully...!!</span>";




}
?>
```

Can you please help me?

Comment: Don't do it, it's a violation of the first normal form and you will regret it later, I promise.

Comment: But If you _really_ want to do it, post the code you have?

Comment: @GordonM i think it is best approach to handle your large data.

Comment: @sunny It's actually the worst approach to handle large data.  The more data you have the more important it becomes to store it properly.

Comment: ^on point, you both.

Comment: @GordonM I use this approach is due to large data. Lets suppose if i want to add new opinion in db then i will create a new column. But when i use implode i will add new opinion in my previous column

Comment: @sunny, Please share your php code too?  `if i want to add new opinion in db then i will create a new column` whatt? :/

Comment: @HawasKaPujaari In my php code there is no implode. In my above picture you can see there is 4 opinions and other fields against every opinion. lets Suppose i have 5 opinion then now i will be create new columns for 5th opinion. But if i use implode then i will be store the data of 5th opinion in old column which i have in my db

Comment: @sunny post a relavent part of your php so people can understand better what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @HawasKaPujaari you can see in my php i use how many variables to insert data. I want to store all opinions data in single variable

Comment: @sunny: You're clearly thinking of your database in terms of a simple flat file.  Databases are a lot more sophisticated than that, as they also model the relationships between data as well as the data itself (hence relational database!).  For what you're trying to do you should consider a dependant table.  If you don't know what that is, then I suggest you do some tutorials on database design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use implode as below

```
$users = [
"Andrew",
"Max",
"Larry",
"Ricardo",
"Lucy",
"Marcus",
"Sophie"
];
print_r(implode('-',$users));
```

but you have to to take all values first in array then use implode to make different values to form a string to store in db. and when you want to use this values you have to explode. in this way only you can use with one column.

Answer (score 0):

Since its already been said that what you are trying to do will violate the `FNF (First Normalization Form)` and clearly you are off track. What I suggest is make a `<form>` and then use the values from it to store in your database (as many as you want without breaking any rules)
And example would be like:

```
<?php
//apply all your checks

//fetching the data

$opinion = $_POST['opinion'];
$rating_type = $_POST['rating_type'];
$action = $_POST['action'];
$outlook = $_POST['outlook'];

//Insert into your database

$que = "INSERT INTO table(opinion, rating_type, action, outlook) Values ('$opinion','$rating_type','$action','$outlook')";
$run = mysql_query($que);
if($run) echo "DATA ENTERED!";

<form method = "POST" action = "">
<label>Opinion</label>
<input type = "text" name = "opinion">
<label>Opinion</label>
<input type = "text" name = "rating_type">
<label>Opinion</label>
<input type = "text" name = "action">
<label>Opinion</label>
<input type = "text" name = "outlook">
 //for as much you want...
<input type = "submit" name = "sub">
</form>
```

This will let you enter as much of data as you want in you database, and when you want see your records simple make a  and apply the `SELECT` query it will display all the records.

> Note: Your code is prone to SQL Injection/XSS. Please study mysqli/PDO
>   before you go live.